# Why this simple WPF command does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I'm trying to add a WPF custom command to a control. What I've done:

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="H.I.S.windows.CommandTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:H.I.S.windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CommandTest" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommand.Save" CanExecute ="SaveCommand_CanExecute"  Executed="SaveCommand_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="local:CustomCommand.Save" Height="50" Width="100">Click me!</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**:

```
namespace H.I.S.windows
{

    public partial class CommandTest : Window
    {
        public CommandTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void SaveCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void SaveCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        }
    }
    public static class CustomCommand
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Save = new RoutedUICommand(
            "Save",
            "Save",
            typeof(CustomCommand),
            new InputGestureCollection()
                {
                    new KeyGesture(Key.F2)
                }
            );
    }
}
```

The button is disabled (even in design mode) and doesn't let the user click on it.
I've just implemented codes described [HERE](https://wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/).
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: The button is only disabled in design mode, but enabled and working at runtime. See https://github.com/SirRufo/so/tree/master/52914821/WpfApp1

Comment: @SirRufo I tried your solution and command worked at runtime bu in mine doesn't work

Comment: But it is **exactly** as you posted - check the MainWindow xaml. If it is not working in your **real** code you did not show us your **real** code

Comment: The button has to be **inside** the definition of the CommandBinding (in your example you define it for the whole window) otherwise you have to set the CommandTarget for the button

Comment: I have updated the sample project with a Test command and two buttons. One is not working and the other is working because of CommandTarget set

Comment: Thank You @SirRufo, Problem solved by setting command target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SirRufo suggested in question comments, Problem was that I declared "CommandBindings" for whole WPF window and button inside another control.

There are 2 solutions for this case:

1: Declaring CommandBindings for Button's direct parent.

2: Set name for control which is bound with command and add some code like below to control:

```
<Window ... x:Name = "windowName" ...>
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="custumCommand:CustomCommands.Save" CanExecute ="CommandBinding_CanExecute"  Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
<StackPanel>
<GroupBox>
<Button Command="custumCommand:CustomCommands.Save" CommandTarget = "{Binding ElementName=windowName}" Content="Save" />
</GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Look at "**CommandTarget**" attribute of Button.

Answer (score 1):

The code what you have posted throws me an error because of this below statement,

```
  <Window.CommandBindings>
          <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommand.Save" CanExecute ="CommandBinding_CanExecute"  Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
```

It started working for me after changing it to below,

```
   <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommand.Save" CanExecute ="SaveCommand_CanExecute"  Executed="SaveCommand_Executed" />
   </Window.CommandBindings>
```

The event handlers in your code-behind are different from what you have in your xaml for CommandBinding.

"SaveCommand_CanExecute" and "SaveCommand_Executed"

After changing as above, it works for me and I can see the messagebox with "Saved" message when I hit click on it.

Hope you are not missing this. If something else stopping you then try to see if it shows any errors on further and let us know.

Comment: Oh, thank you G K problem was not what you said it was just a mistake from me while coping codes. I've changed the code a bit to be more understandable. unfortunately, the problem is still running.